# postgres daylight savings timezone

Tags: postgresql, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a postgres table with a column which is timestamp with timezone. The data stored is in UTC. I want to convert this column from UTC to different time zones. How do i select the correct timezone which will take the daylight savings into account in postgres? I have had a look at the pg_timezone_names view and am aware of the actual supported abbrev by postgres. My concern is that certain states like California use a PST and PDT for parts of the year.

I suspect, a code like `select current_time at time zone 'PDT'`, or `select current_time at time zone 'PST'` won't give me the correct current time in California all year. Have I understood this right?

I am aware that I could do sometime like `select current_time at time zone 'America/New_York'` or `America/Los_Angeles`. I expect something like this to take into account the day light savings time as I have explicitly specified the location. Is this the only correct way to handle the daylight savings issue in postgres?

Ideally, I do not want to specify locations explicitly and would have preferred to go with postgres timezone abbreviation. Can that be done at all?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question as you. The best I can offer is to point to their documentation page, which I just found. [pg_timezone_names documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/view-pg-timezone-names.html)

> The view pg_timezone_names provides a list of time zone names that are
>   recognized by SET TIMEZONE, along with their associated abbreviations,
>   UTC offsets, and daylight-savings status. Unlike the abbreviations
>   shown in pg_timezone_abbrevs, many of these names imply a set of
>   daylight-savings transition date rules. Therefore, the associated
>   information changes across local DST boundaries. The displayed
>   information is computed based on the current value of
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

I think this makes sense and is the best we can hope for. Time zone abbreviations unfortunately do not encompass DST rules, I think because no specific geographic region can be implied, therefore they are just symbols for UTC offsets.